# How do I get the selected image style from a referenced media field?

Tags: entities, blocks, 9

I created a custom block with an entity reference to a media field (field_background_image).
In the display settings I have chosen 'Thumbnail' as format and selected a custom image style 'background'.

In `my _preprocess_block(&$variables)` function I would like to get the selected format (thumbnail) and especially the selected image style ('background').
How can I load both these information from the $variables?

Comment: `composer require drupal/devel_kint_extras && drush -y en devel_kint_extras && drush cr`: This enables the Devel module, flushes cache, and now you can put `ksm($variables);` inside your preprocess to inspect the variables, visit the page and see what you find in there.